# Finding integers solutions for x² - y² = x + 2xy + y, and then proving some properties they seem to have

Tags: diophantine-equations, integers

I've found about 19 integer solutions, but they follow a very strange pattern.

x = 6, y = 2

35, 14

204, 84

1189, 492

Notice that every one of them equals the previous one times (3 + 2√2), and then rounded up. This is also true for every other integer solution I've found.

The ratio of x/y of all integer solutions approaches 2√2.

Note that the curve is not linear.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation)

Comment: There is a simple explanation for the ratio: $x^2-2xy-y^2=(x-(1+\sqrt2)y)(x-(1-\sqrt2)y)$. You are nearing the asymptotes of an hyperbola.

Comment: Cf. the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences [here](https://oeis.org/A001109) and [here](https://oeis.org/A053141)

Comment: Did you mean the ratio $x/y$ approaches $1+\sqrt2$?  $1189/492=2.41\overline6\approx2.414\approx 1+\sqrt2$

Answer (score 1):

Short version:  call the pairs $(x_n, y_n),$
and number $(x_0, y_0)= (0,0) \; , \; \; $
$(x_1, y_1)= (6,2) \; , \; \; $
$(x_2, y_2)= (35,14) \; , \; \; $
$(x_3, y_3)= (204,84) \; , \; \; $
we get rules (for my $n \geq 1$ )
$$ \color{red}{ x_{n+2}  = 6 x_{n+1}  - x_n \; , } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{ y_{n+2}  = 6y_{n+1}  - y_n + 2 \; .} $$

We could then solve for $x_n$ as $A (3 + \sqrt 8)^n + B (3 - \sqrt 8)^n $  by

In order to calculate $y,$  take instead $ z_n= y_n + \frac{1}{2},$  you may now solve for $z_n$ as $C (3 + \sqrt 8)^n + D (3 - \sqrt 8)^n$ because
$ z_{n+2}  = 6 z_{n+1}  - z_n \; .$

ORIGINAL:

Here are the first few solutions to $w^2 - 2 v^2 = -1$  with both $w,v >0.$

See how the sequence $w_n$  obeys $w_{n+2}  = 6 w_{n+1} - w_n, $  while $v_n$
$v_{n+2}  = 6 v_{n+1} - v_n. $  We always get these Fibonacci type sequences, in our case one pair suffices.

Next,   the thing you are setting equal to zero  (times 4)  comes out to
$$  (2x-2y-1)^2 - 2(2y+1)^2 + 1,  $$  so the desired equation comes out
$$ \color{red}{ (2x-2y-1)^2 - 2(2y+1)^2 = -1. }  $$

The annoying thing is that we need to allow four types of $x,y$ pairs (from positive $w,v$  from  four choices
$$  2x-2y + 1 = w \; , \; \; \; 2y+1 = v \; , \; $$
$$  2x-2y + 1 = w \; , \; \; \; 2y+1 = -v \; , \; $$
$$  2x-2y + 1 = -w \; , \; \; \; 2y+1 = v \; , \; $$
$$  2x-2y + 1 = -w \; , \; \; \; 2y+1 = -v \; . \; $$
For each of these we may solve for $y$ in terms of $v,$ then plug back in to solve for $x$  in terms of both $w,v.$

From your question, it appears that you prefer $ x > y > 0,$  that is going to mean the first choice, so  we are getting
$$   x = \frac{w+v }{2}  \; , \; \;  y = \frac{v-1}{2}   $$

---

```
 w^2 - 2 v^2 = -1 =   -1 *  1 

1,  7,  41,  239,  1393,  8119,  47321,  275807,  1607521,  

1,  5,  29,  169,  985,  5741,  33461,  195025,  1136689,
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is $x^2-(2y+1)x-(y+y^2)=0$.

Solving this quadratic, $x=\dfrac{2y+1\pm\sqrt{(2y+1)^2+4(y+y^2)}}2=\dfrac{2y+1\pm\sqrt{8y^2+8y+1}}2.$

You can already see that $\dfrac xy=\dfrac{2+\frac1y\pm\sqrt{8+\frac8y+\frac1{y^2}}}2$ approaches $1+\sqrt2$ as $y\to\infty$.

In order for this $x$ to be an integer, $z=\sqrt{8y^2+8y+1}=\sqrt{2(2y+1)^2-1}$

must be an odd integer, and we must have $z^2-2Y^2=-1$, where $Y=2y+1$.

This is the well-known [negative Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#The_negative_Pell_equation), whose solutions are as follows:

$z=1,7,41,239,1393\dots$ and $Y=1,5,29,169,985\dots$, so we have $y=0,2,14,84,492\dots$.

The [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/A053141) gives the closed formula

$y_n = \dfrac{-4+(2+\sqrt2)(3+2\sqrt2)^n + (2-\sqrt2)(3-2\sqrt2)^n}8$,

and since $(2-\sqrt2)(3-2\sqrt2)^n<1$, I think from here you can see

that the next term is the previous term times $3+2\sqrt2$, rounded up.